# What (open source) audio manipulation programs are most popular with Blender users?

Tags: audio

I've mostly used VLC, however I'd like to explore audio manipulation at a more in-depth level (for added effect to animations).

I've been poking around Audacity, but I don't want to invest time in an application to use with Blender, if it isn't the best one to use with Blender.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what features do you need, what OS must be supported, must it be free or is there a budget (how much) available?

Comment: @360ueck - Which is more popular for blender is really a question for a poll on the  blender mailing list.

Comment: @ Steve Barnes. You don't need to "@" the original poster. What mailing list? I've already asked this on Blender and was prompted to it move here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Ardour](https://ardour.org/).

It's not much of an "audio manipulation" software it's a whole "Digital Audio Workstation". I've used it for sometime before.

It's open source. It's available for Linux and Mac. It needs you to have ["Jack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit) installed to run.

You can mix tracks. You can apply effects on tracks. You can record. You can add synthesizers. *It's definitely full of features but may require some time to learn to start moving around.*

Comment: Thanks, would you recommend Ardour over Audacity?

Comment: Well like we said, they're different. Audacity's more of an audio manipulation tool but Ardour's a DAW. Audacity's great too & I use it also. See what suits your needs :)

Comment: Ok, I didnt get you were saying Audacity's an AMT from your answer but thanks.